# gradlew flywaymigrate and Access denied for user

Tags: java, mysql, gradle, flyway

I can connect to mysql fine using the userid/password but when I do with gradlew, I am getting this error:

```
C:\dev\project>gradlew flywayMigrate -Dflyway.password=*****
> Configure project :
Running gradle version: 4.10.3
> Task :Core:flywayMigrate FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':Core:flywayMigrate'.
> Error occurred while executing flywayMigrate
  Unable to obtain connection from database (jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sr?serverTimezone=UTC) for user 'userid': Access denied for user 'userid'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  SQL State  : 28000
  Error Code : 1045
  Message    : Access denied for user 'userid'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
  Access denied for user 'userid'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Verified in profile-dev.gradle the userid and password is correct. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It worked by just skipping the password

```
gradlew flywayMigrate
```

Thank you!